# Why declared character as '' (empty) throws exception?

Tags: java, exception

I have written following code

```
class JavaApplication1{
public static void main(String...strarr) throws Exception{
    char c = '';
    c = 'c';
    System.out.println(c);
}}
```

> **Output**: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type:   at
>   javaapplication1.JavaApplication1.main(JavaApplication1.java:6)

I didnt get that why it is throwing exception? 
Your response will be greatly appreciated

Comment: `''` is not a valid character in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  char c = '';
```

Since `''`  is not a valid character and java compiler complaining about it.

From [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

> The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

[List you can user as **char**](http://www.ssec.wisc.edu/~tomw/java/unicode.html)

In the above list you can use the first table set elements as a `char`

Answer (score 1):

'' is not a valid character in java.By default char is initialized to 'uffff'

Answer (score 0):

Because for some unknown reason it's not supported. Just use

```
char c = 0;
```

or

```
char c = (char) -1;
```

instead to define nullity.